# Not able to set or access any data in jest test (vue)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I can't seem to get any tests to pass for one of my vue components. The component has the following data points that are set on mounted:

```
data() {
    return {
      userData: {},
      notes: [],
    }
  },
```

I attempted to do the following simple test to see if the parent component, `Notebook.vue` renders a child component `NotebookBody.vue`:

```
test('notebook renders notebook-body', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Notebook);
    expect(wrapper.findComponent(NotebookBody)).toBe(true);
})
```

I got the error about the child component:

```
 [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "userData". Expected Object, got Undefined in <NotebookBody>
```

In my component `Notebook`, when `NotebookBody` is called, the data `notes` and `userData` is passed to `NotebookBody` as props.

I assumed that I need to set `notes` and  `userData` in the Notebook wrapper before I run my `expect` so I tried created two consts with dummy data called `testNotes` and `testUserData` and tried to set it like this before I run `expect`:

```
wrapper.setData( { 
  notes: testNotes, 
  userData: testUserData
} );
```

However I still get the same issue, of `userData undefined in NotebookBody`

I've also tried setting the data when I create the wrapper like this:

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(Notebook, { propData: { userData: testUserData } });
```

But I still get the same issue. What am I doing wrong?

---- EDIT ----

I created a new test to attempt to see if I can just see if the notes data element even exists and I get the same errors, userData and notes just are undefined!!! How do I fix this?

```
test('notebook notes exist', done =>  {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Notebook);

    wrapper.setData({ userData: testUserData, notes: testNotes });

    expect(notes.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
})
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this (`wrapper.setData()` works as expected for me). Can you link to a reproduction?

Comment: @tony19 here's an extremely simplified version of my code https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-nightingale-tg5wn?file=/src/tests/Notebook.spec.jest

Comment: Still can't reproduce the problem. I tried it with Vue CLI 4.5.11 and 5.0.0-alpha.4.